# Find open reading frames in a DNA sequence

Tags: python, homework

I have a fast file containing DNA sequences. I've already cleaned the file and has only DNA sequences with no gaps or errors or white space characters. I want to find open reading frames in the fasta file that are longer than 30 bp.

Here's a little description: An open reading frame is defined by a sequence that

1. start with `ATG`,
2. ends with `TAG`, `TAA`, or `TGA`,
3. is a multiple of three.

For each open reading frame, I want to print the start position in the sequence, the length of the open reading frame, and the open reading frame sequence to the screen. Then I want to print the total number of open reading frames found. I would appreciate some help.

I can't use libraries.

Also, here's the DNA sequence I am working with:

```
GCATGCAATACAGTGACATATATATATACCCTAACACTACCCTAACCCTACCCTATTTCA
ACCCTTCCAACCTGTCTCTCAACTTACCCTCACATTACCCTACCTCTCCACTTGTTACCC
TGTCCCATTCAACCATACCACTCCCAACCACCATCCATCCCTCTACTTACTACCACCAAT
CAACCGTCCACCATAACCGTTACCCTCCAATTAGCCATATTCAACTTCACTACCACTTAC
CCTGCCATTACTCTACCATCCACCATCTGCTACTCACCATACTGTTGTTCTACCCTCCAT
ATTGAAACGTTAACAAATGATCGTAAATAATACACATATACTTACCCTACCACTTTATAC
CACCACACATCACATGCCATACTCACCTTCACTTGTATACTGATATGCCATACGCACACG
GATGCTACAGTATATACCACTCTCAAACTTACCCTACTCTCACATTCTACTCCACTCCAT
GACCCATCTCTCACTAAATCAGTACTAAATGCACCCACATCATTATGCACGGCACTTGCC
TCAGCGGTCTATACCCTGAGCCATTTACCCATAACTCCCACGATTATCCACATTTTAATA
TCTATATCTCATTCGGCGGGCCCAAATATTGTATAACTGCTCTTAATACATACGTTATAC
CACTTTTGCACCATATACTAACCACTCAAATTATATACACTTATGCCAATATAACCAAAA
AATTACCACTAAAATCACCTAAACATAAAAATTATTTATCTTTCAACTTTACGAAATAAA
CACACTCAATTGCGTATCTATACCACCATGACGTCATTAACGTAAAAGTTCCTTAATATT
ACCATTTGCTTGAACGGATACCATTTCAGAATATTTCTAACTTTCACAGACCATACATTA
GAATAATATGCCACCTCACTGTCGTAACACTCTATATTCACCGAGAAACAATACGGTAGT
GGCTCAAACTCATGCCGGTGCTATGATACAATTGTATCCTATTTCCATTCTCATATGCTA
TCCGCAATATCCTAAAAGCATAACTGATGCATCTTTAATCTTGTATGTGACACTACTCAT
ACGAAGAGACTATATCTAAAGAAGACGATACAGTGATATGTACGTTGTTTTTGTAGAATT
ATAATGAAACGTCAAATAACCCTACTATATTATAACTTATCAGCGCCGTATACTAAAACG
GACGTTACGATATTGTCTCACTTCATCTTACCACCCTCTATCTTATTGTTGATAAAACAC
TAACCCCTCAGCTTTATTTCTAGTTACAGTTACAACAAACTATCCCAAACCATAAATCTT
AATATTTTAGGTGTCAAAAAATGAGGATCTCCAAATGAGAGTTTGGTACCATGACTTGTA
ACTCCACTACCCTGATCTGCAATCTTGTTCTTAGAAGTGACGCATACTCTATATGGCCCG
ACGCGACGCGCCAAAAAATGAAAAAAGAAGCAGCGACTCATTTTTATGGAAGGACAAAGT
GCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGTTAGCTTT
ATTACCGTCCACGCTTTTTCTACAATAGTGTAAAAGTTTCTTTCTTATGTTCATCGTATT
CATAAAATGCTTCACGAACACCGTCATTGATCAAATAGGTTTATAATATTAATATACATT
TATATAATCGGCGGTATTTATATCATCAAAAAAAGTAGTTTTTTATTTTATTTTTTCATT
ACTTTTCACTGTCTATGGATTTTCATTCGTAAAGGCATCACTCCCTAGTTTGCGATAGTG
TAGATACCGTCCTTGGATAGAGCACTGGAGATGGCTGGCTTTAATCTGCTGGAGTACCAT
GGAACACCGGTGATCATTCTGGTCACTTGGTCTGGGGCAATACCAGTCAACATGGTGGTG
AAGTCACCGTAGTTGAAAACGGCTTCAGCAACTTCGACTGGGTAGGTTTCAGTTGGGTGG
GCGGCTTGGAACATGTAGTATTGGGCCAAGTGAGCTCTGATATCAGAGACGTAGACACCC
AATTCCACCAAGTTGACTCTTTCGTCAGATTGAGCTAGAGTGGTGGTTGCAGAAAGCAGT
AGCAGCGATGGCAGCGACACCAGCAGCGATTGAAGTTAATTTGACCATTGTATTTGTTTT
GTTTGTTAGTGCTGATGTAATCTTAACAAGAAATAGTGAAATGAAAGCGCATACCTCAAA
GGCATATAGTTGAAGCAGCTCTATTTATACCCGTTCCTCCATCTGTCATCACTACTTAAA
CGATTCGTTAACAGACGCTCATTTAGCACCTCACATATTCTCCATATCTCATCTTTCACA
CAATCTCATTATCTCTATGGAGATGCTCTTGTTTCTGAACGAATCATACATCTTTCATAG
GTTTCGTATGTGGAGTATTGTTTTATGGCACTCATGTGTATTCGTATGCGCAGAATGTGG
GAATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAA
GTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTTTAGATTTGGACCCTCGTTCAGAAGC
TTACTGTCTAAGCCATCATTTGGTGTGTCCTAAACGGTTTCCATGCAAAGCAACATCTTT
GTTACTCATTCCTGAAGGTTGAATAAAAAATAGCAACCATGTGCAGGGAGTCGTATATTG
TTAGATTCTAGAGACTTGTACGCATCATCAAAGCTGTAAATAGAATAAACATACGCAAGG
CGTCAAAAGTGCATAGTTAAGAAAATTCCTGACATGTGAAAATATGTGTTTATGAAATGT
GTCAAGGCCCGTCTATAGCGTAGTTAACCCCTCTGCAGGAGTAAGTGACTTTTTTTACGC
TCAAAAGGCAACGAGGGCACATACTTAAAAGTCATTTTCAAACACATCTGCAGTTTGCAA
CGACAGATAACAATATTATGATAGGATGGTATGATGTTATTAGCTGCCACATATTTTTAA
TAATAGCATTAGTCACGTCTCTTCAATTGTTGGGATGAAACTCTAAAATATCATTCCTTT
AGTAGTATTCCAGTTACCAGTATATTATCACATGCCGAAAAAGAAGATGACATAAAGATC
GACAAACAGTCTTCAAATATAATGGAAGCTGGAATGCAAGGATTGATAATGTAACAGGAT
ACTGAATGACAAAGTATAAATGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGTAGTAATACTATTATGT
GGAAATACCGATTCCATTTTGAGGATTCCAATTGTTGGAATAAAAATCAACTATCATCTA
CTAACTAGTATTTACGTTACTAGTATATTATCATATACGGTGTTAGAAGATGACGCAAAT
GATGAGAAATAGTCATCTAAATTAGTGGAAGCTGAAACGCAAGGATTGATAATGTAATAG
GATCAATGAATATTAACATATAAAACGATGATAATAATATTTATAGAATTGTGTAGAATT
GCAGATTCCCTTTTATGGATTCCTAAATCCTGGAGGAGAACTTCTAGTATATCTACATAC
CTAATATTATAGCCTTAATCACAATGGAATCCCAACAATTACATCAAAATCCACATTCTC
TACACCAATACCATCGACGAGAGCTTCTAGTAAATTGTATACATAACAGTATAACCCTTA
CCAACAATGGAATCTCAAAGATTATTAAATTATTCACAGACTCTGAGGATTCGGGTAAAA
TAGGGTATTTAACTGGTTACCGGAAAGGTTTAGAAAATTCGTGGAGGGTTGGCCGAGTGG
TCTAAGGCGGCAGACTTAAGATCTGTTGGACGGTTGTCCGCGCGAGTTCGAACCTCGCAT
TCATTTTCCGGATCCACTTTATAGTGGGTCACTTCATCTCTTGTAGGGTTCACTGAAAGA
TAATCAATCAAATTATCATATGACCAATGGGTCACTTTTTTGATGAGACCCATGTTTATT
CTTCTATACGTTCGTGATACTGCACTTACGACTACCAGTAACATCAGAATAACCATAGAG
CTTATGCTATCTTGAAATATATCATCGCCGTAAAGTATGATGTGTAGCGCATTAGTCTTC
TGCATTCATATTATCAGTGGTATACCGTTTGGTATATGCTTTCCAATCATGAAGTGTTGG
CTCTACTCTATATAAATTCGACATCCATTGATTTTCTCAATAAATGAGTTACCCAAGTAA
GCTTTCCATTGATACAAGTGATCTACATTCTTGCGACGCCAAATTATAAAGCACTAAAAA
TCATATCATACCCAATTGCGGGCAGCACATGTATATATTATACACTACTTATAACTAACC
TTCTTCATATATAACAATATGCCTGATAATACTAATGCATTTAAATCATATCATGAAAGA
AAATTACATGGGTTTTATTGACATAATTGCATTTAGAATACATAAAATTCTAAAGAATTA
ATATATCCAAAGTATTAGACATAACCAAGAATAATAGTGAATAATTTTAGATTTTGTTAC
ATATAATTCTGCTTGCCTATCTCTTCCACTCTTTTCAAAACGTTGCATGTAAGCGTTACT
AATATTCCGCTTTATTTTGTTGCAATTCCTAATTTTTTCATTACATTATCTTGCGAGTAC
GGAAGCGATTAACGTTCTCCCAATAGAAGGAACAAACATAGATATTGAAGTTTTACTGCT
TTTGCTTACCTGACCTTTTTCAAATTTAATTTTTTCCCGCTAATAAGACCATAAACTACC
CCGAACCAAATTCTAAAAGATAGTCAGCTGGATTAGAGTTGTCATCTCCAAACATTAATT
TTGCATTATCTTCGGCTTCAATCAAATCGCCTGATAAGAACTCCTTTAATTCTTCATGAA
TGTTTGTATGTGGATGACTCTCCATAGTGCCAGCATGATTGTGGTTACCGACCGAATCAT
ATAACGGTGGCTCCCAATTGTGCAATTCAGCCTTACTATTTTGTTCATTCATCAAAGCAT
TTGGGACAGATCTAATATCTATAATTCTTTCCTCACTATTCTCGCTATTATTTTGCCCCG
AACTGGCATGGTGGTTATTGGTAAAAGGAGATAATGCTGCGACAGAACTTTTCTTCTCTT
CCAATTCTTTTATCTTCGCCAATAACGCCTTCTTTTTTCGTGCTTGTATTTCTAAAATTT
CGGCCAGGTATTGTAAATATTCGACCGTTCTATCCAAAATGATACCCTTATTTGGTTTGA
TTTGTTTACCTAGGTCATCGTAATTCAATAAAGATGGTGGAACCAACTGGCCGAGTTCTT
TTATCTTTTGCTTTATTAATTCTCTTCTTCTCCTTTCGACGGCATTATGAAACTCTCTTT
TGCGCCTCAGTTTCTCATCAGAAGTTAACCCGCCTAAAATCTTTGGAACACTTCCAGGTC
CTATATTTTCAGTCATATTGCTACTTATTGAAGTGTGTCTTGTTCTGGGTGTGTTTATGC
TACCATGCCTAAAAGAAGATGAAAGGAAACTTCCTGCACGAAATGACGATGATGGTGATC
TTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAG
AAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAATTGATGCTAGAAGATAAAG
AGGAGCTCAAATCATCAGTTAAGTTATACATTGTGTCATCGGTGCCATGCTGAAATAAAA
AGTCATGTGGTAACTCAGCTTTTAAGCCTTCTTGTTGCTGTAATGGAGTATTCATTGCTC
```

Comment: "I can't use libraries." - why not? Is this an assignment question?

Comment: The answer looks like homework.

Answer (score 1):

ok I have a Python attempt, used `Biopython` only to load your DNA sequence;
working only on your sequence ( not calculating the reverse complement) and as per your instruction an ORF is something in between an ATG and a stop codon, so I am using every ATG as a start even if preceded by another ATG, lenght of ORFs is >30bp meaning >90 bases. Code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
# record = SeqIO.read("sample_test.fasta", "fasta")
# record = SeqIO.read("sample_test_2.fasta", "fasta")

record = SeqIO.read("sample.fasta", "fasta")

# print(record.seq)
# print(len(sequence))

sequence = record.seq

orfs = []

for i in range(len(sequence)-2):
    
    if sequence[i]+sequence[i+1]+sequence[i+2] == 'ATG':
    
        print('ATG at : ', i)
                
        orf = 'ATG'
        x = 3
        while sequence[i+x:i+3+x] not in ['TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA'] and i+x < len(sequence):                    
            orf += sequence[i+x:i+3+x]
            x += 3
        if len(orf) > 90:   
            orfs.append((i, orf , len(orf)))

cnt = 1
for i in orfs:
    
    print('\nsequence number : ', cnt ,'\nstart : ', i[0] ,'\nframe : ',  ((len(sequence)-len(sequence[i[0]:]))%3)+1 ,
          '\nsequence : ', i[1],'\nlenght sequence :', i[2],'\n\n')
    cnt += 1
```

Result, start is with a sequence that goes from 0 to len(sequence)-1:

```
sequence number :  1 
start :  2 
frame :  3 
sequence :  ATGCAATACAGTGACATATATATATACCCTAACACTACCCTAACCCTACCCTATTTCAACCCTTCCAACCTGTCTCTCAACTTACCCTCACATTACCCTACCTCTCCACTTGTTACCCTGTCCCATTCAACCATACCACTCCCAACCACCATCCATCCCTCTACTTACTACCACCAATCAACCGTCCACCATAACCGTTACCCTCCAATTAGCCATATTCAACTTCACTACCACTTACCCTGCCATTACTCTACCATCCACCATCTGCTACTCACCATACTGTTGTTCTACCCTCCATAT 
lenght sequence : 300 



sequence number :  2 
start :  524 
frame :  3 
sequence :  ATGCACGGCACTTGCCTCAGCGGTCTATACCCTGAGCCATTTACCCATAACTCCCACGATTATCCACATTTTAATATCTATATCTCATTCGGCGGGCCCAAATATTGTATAACTGCTCTTAATACATACGTTATACCACTTTTGCACCATATACTAACCACTCAAATTATATACACTTATGCCAATATAACCAAAAAATTACCACTAAAATCACCTAAACATAAAAATTATTTATCTTTCAACTTTACGAAA 
lenght sequence : 252 



sequence number :  3 
start :  907 
frame :  2 
sequence :  ATGCCACCTCACTGTCGTAACACTCTATATTCACCGAGAAACAATACGGTAGTGGCTCAAACTCATGCCGGTGCTATGATACAATTGTATCCTATTTCCATTCTCATATGCTATCCGCAATATCCTAAAAGCATAACTGATGCATCTTTAATCTTGTATGTGACACTACTCATACGAAGAGACTATATC 
lenght sequence : 189 



sequence number :  4 
start :  982 
frame :  2 
sequence :  ATGATACAATTGTATCCTATTTCCATTCTCATATGCTATCCGCAATATCCTAAAAGCATAACTGATGCATCTTTAATCTTGTATGTGACACTACTCATACGAAGAGACTATATC 
lenght sequence : 114 



sequence number :  5 
start :  1143 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGAAACGTCAAATAACCCTACTATATTATAACTTATCAGCGCCGTATACTAAAACGGACGTTACGATATTGTCTCACTTCATCTTACCACCCTCTATCTTATTGTTGATAAAACAC 
lenght sequence : 117 



sequence number :  6 
start :  1370 
frame :  3 
sequence :  ATGACTTGTAACTCCACTACCCTGATCTGCAATCTTGTTCTTAGAAGTGACGCATACTCTATATGGCCCGACGCGACGCGCCAAAAAATGAAAAAAGAAGCAGCGACTCATTTTTATGGAAGGACAAAGTGCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGT 
lenght sequence : 183 



sequence number :  7 
start :  1432 
frame :  2 
sequence :  ATGGCCCGACGCGACGCGCCAAAAAATGAAAAAAGAAGCAGCGACTCATTTTTATGGAAGGACAAAGTGCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGTTAGCTTTATTACCGTCCACGCTTTTTCTACAA 
lenght sequence : 153 



sequence number :  8 
start :  1457 
frame :  3 
sequence :  ATGAAAAAAGAAGCAGCGACTCATTTTTATGGAAGGACAAAGTGCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGT 
lenght sequence : 96 



sequence number :  9 
start :  1485 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGGAAGGACAAAGTGCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGTTAGCTTTATTACCGTCCACGCTTTTTCTACAATAGTG 
lenght sequence : 105 



sequence number :  10 
start :  1830 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGGCTGGCTTTAATCTGCTGGAGTACCATGGAACACCGGTGATCATTCTGGTCACTTGGTCTGGGGCAATACCAGTCAACATGGTGGTGAAGTCACCG 
lenght sequence : 99 



sequence number :  11 
start :  2107 
frame :  2 
sequence :  ATGGCAGCGACACCAGCAGCGATTGAAGTTAATTTGACCATTGTATTTGTTTTGTTTGTTAGTGCTGATGTAATCTTAACAAGAAATAGTGAAATGAAAGCGCATACCTCAAAGGCATATAGT 
lenght sequence : 123 



sequence number :  12 
start :  2356 
frame :  2 
sequence :  ATGGAGATGCTCTTGTTTCTGAACGAATCATACATCTTTCATAGGTTTCGTATGTGGAGTATTGTTTTATGGCACTCATGTGTATTCGTATGCGCAGAATGTGGGAATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAAGTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTTTAGATTTGGACCCTCGTTCAGAAGCTTACTGTCTAAGCCATCATTTGGTGTGTCCTAAACGGTTTCCATGCAAAGCAACATCTTTGTTACTCATTCCTGAAGGT 
lenght sequence : 303 



sequence number :  13 
start :  2362 
frame :  2 
sequence :  ATGCTCTTGTTTCTGAACGAATCATACATCTTTCATAGGTTTCGTATGTGGAGTATTGTTTTATGGCACTCATGTGTATTCGTATGCGCAGAATGTGGGAATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAAGTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTTTAGATTTGGACCCTCGTTCAGAAGCTTACTGTCTAAGCCATCATTTGGTGTGTCCTAAACGGTTTCCATGCAAAGCAACATCTTTGTTACTCATTCCTGAAGGT 
lenght sequence : 297 



sequence number :  14 
start :  2407 
frame :  2 
sequence :  ATGTGGAGTATTGTTTTATGGCACTCATGTGTATTCGTATGCGCAGAATGTGGGAATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAAGTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTTTAGATTTGGACCCTCGTTCAGAAGCTTACTGTCTAAGCCATCATTTGGTGTGTCCTAAACGGTTTCCATGCAAAGCAACATCTTTGTTACTCATTCCTGAAGGT 
lenght sequence : 252 



sequence number :  15 
start :  2462 
frame :  3 
sequence :  ATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAAGTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTT 
lenght sequence : 93 



sequence number :  16 
start :  3447 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGATAATAATATTTATAGAATTGTGTAGAATTGCAGATTCCCTTTTATGGATTCCTAAATCCTGGAGGAGAACTTCTAGTATATCTACATACCTAATATTA 
lenght sequence : 102 



sequence number :  17 
start :  3563 
frame :  3 
sequence :  ATGGAATCCCAACAATTACATCAAAATCCACATTCTCTACACCAATACCATCGACGAGAGCTTCTAGTAAATTGTATACATAACAGTATAACCCTTACCAACAATGGAATCTCAAAGATTATTAAATTATTCACAGACTCTGAGGATTCGGGTAAAATAGGGTATTTAACTGGTTACCGGAAAGGTTTAGAAAATTCGTGGAGGGTTGGCCGAGTGGTC 
lenght sequence : 219 



sequence number :  18 
start :  4056 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGATGTGTAGCGCATTAGTCTTCTGCATTCATATTATCAGTGGTATACCGTTTGGTATATGCTTTCCAATCATGAAGTGTTGGCTCTACTCTATA 
lenght sequence : 96 



sequence number :  19 
start :  4059 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGTGTAGCGCATTAGTCTTCTGCATTCATATTATCAGTGGTATACCGTTTGGTATATGCTTTCCAATCATGAAGTGTTGGCTCTACTCTATA 
lenght sequence : 93 



sequence number :  20 
start :  5073 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGCTGCGACAGAACTTTTCTTCTCTTCCAATTCTTTTATCTTCGCCAATAACGCCTTCTTTTTTCGTGCTTGTATTTCTAAAATTTCGGCCAGGTATTGTAAATATTCGACCGTTCTATCCAAAA 
lenght sequence : 126 



sequence number :  21 
start :  5253 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGGTGGAACCAACTGGCCGAGTTCTTTTATCTTTTGCTTTATTAATTCTCTTCTTCTCCTTTCGACGGCATTATGAAACTCTCTTTTGCGCCTCAGTTTCTCATCAGAAGTTAACCCGCCTAAAATCTTTGGAACACTTCCAGGTCCTATATTTTCAGTCATATTGCTACTTATTGAAGTGTGTCTTGTTCTGGGTGTGTTTATGCTACCATGCC 
lenght sequence : 216 



sequence number :  22 
start :  5456 
frame :  3 
sequence :  ATGCTACCATGCCTAAAAGAAGATGAAAGGAAACTTCCTGCACGAAATGACGATGATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTA 
lenght sequence : 120 



sequence number :  23 
start :  5478 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGAAAGGAAACTTCCTGCACGAAATGACGATGATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAGAAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAAT 
lenght sequence : 144 



sequence number :  24 
start :  5502 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGACGATGATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAGAAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAAT 
lenght sequence : 120 



sequence number :  25 
start :  5508 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAGAAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAAT 
lenght sequence : 114 



sequence number :  26 
start :  5511 
frame :  1 
sequence :  ATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAGAAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAAT 
lenght sequence : 111
```

I am sure there is some awk, perl, regex way to get the same in much less lines.

Comment: Thank you for your edit

Comment: I am gonna post another answer using regex copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114246/how-to-find-a-open-reading-frame-in-python please feel free to edit it solving the start position problem

Comment: Thanks @pippo1980 good you've done this thanks upvoted again. The protein is now identified and a better approach IMO is to map against the genome.

Answer (score 1):

using an unwanted (regex library) I can steal code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114246/how-to-find-a-open-reading-frame-in-python , code :

```
import re


from Bio import SeqIO
# record = SeqIO.read("sample_test.fasta", "fasta")
# record = SeqIO.read("sample_test_2.fasta", "fasta")

record = SeqIO.read("sample.fasta", "fasta")

# print(record.seq)
# print(len(sequence))

sequence = str(record.seq)


pattern = re.compile(r'(?=(ATG(?:...)*?)(?=TAG|TGA|TAA))')


revcompseq = sequence[::-1].maketrans("ATGC", "TACG") #reverse complement

# print (pattern.findall(sequence)) #forward search
# print (pattern.findall(sequence[::-1].translate(revcompseq))) #backward search


a = pattern.findall(sequence)

# print(type(a))


cnt = 1
for i in a:
    if len(i) > 90:
        print('\nnumero = ',cnt,'\n',i ,'\nlenght = ', len(i),'\n---------------------------\n\n')
        cnt += 1
```

output :

```
numero =  1 
 ATGCAATACAGTGACATATATATATACCCTAACACTACCCTAACCCTACCCTATTTCAACCCTTCCAACCTGTCTCTCAACTTACCCTCACATTACCCTACCTCTCCACTTGTTACCCTGTCCCATTCAACCATACCACTCCCAACCACCATCCATCCCTCTACTTACTACCACCAATCAACCGTCCACCATAACCGTTACCCTCCAATTAGCCATATTCAACTTCACTACCACTTACCCTGCCATTACTCTACCATCCACCATCTGCTACTCACCATACTGTTGTTCTACCCTCCATAT 
lenght =  300 
---------------------------



numero =  2 
 ATGCACGGCACTTGCCTCAGCGGTCTATACCCTGAGCCATTTACCCATAACTCCCACGATTATCCACATTTTAATATCTATATCTCATTCGGCGGGCCCAAATATTGTATAACTGCTCTTAATACATACGTTATACCACTTTTGCACCATATACTAACCACTCAAATTATATACACTTATGCCAATATAACCAAAAAATTACCACTAAAATCACCTAAACATAAAAATTATTTATCTTTCAACTTTACGAAA 
lenght =  252 
---------------------------



numero =  3 
 ATGCCACCTCACTGTCGTAACACTCTATATTCACCGAGAAACAATACGGTAGTGGCTCAAACTCATGCCGGTGCTATGATACAATTGTATCCTATTTCCATTCTCATATGCTATCCGCAATATCCTAAAAGCATAACTGATGCATCTTTAATCTTGTATGTGACACTACTCATACGAAGAGACTATATC 
lenght =  189 
---------------------------



numero =  4 
 ATGATACAATTGTATCCTATTTCCATTCTCATATGCTATCCGCAATATCCTAAAAGCATAACTGATGCATCTTTAATCTTGTATGTGACACTACTCATACGAAGAGACTATATC 
lenght =  114 
---------------------------



numero =  5 
 ATGAAACGTCAAATAACCCTACTATATTATAACTTATCAGCGCCGTATACTAAAACGGACGTTACGATATTGTCTCACTTCATCTTACCACCCTCTATCTTATTGTTGATAAAACAC 
lenght =  117 
---------------------------



numero =  6 
 ATGACTTGTAACTCCACTACCCTGATCTGCAATCTTGTTCTTAGAAGTGACGCATACTCTATATGGCCCGACGCGACGCGCCAAAAAATGAAAAAAGAAGCAGCGACTCATTTTTATGGAAGGACAAAGTGCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGT 
lenght =  183 
---------------------------



numero =  7 
 ATGGCCCGACGCGACGCGCCAAAAAATGAAAAAAGAAGCAGCGACTCATTTTTATGGAAGGACAAAGTGCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGTTAGCTTTATTACCGTCCACGCTTTTTCTACAA 
lenght =  153 
---------------------------



numero =  8 
 ATGAAAAAAGAAGCAGCGACTCATTTTTATGGAAGGACAAAGTGCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGT 
lenght =  96 
---------------------------



numero =  9 
 ATGGAAGGACAAAGTGCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGTTAGCTTTATTACCGTCCACGCTTTTTCTACAATAGTG 
lenght =  105 
---------------------------



numero =  10 
 ATGGCTGGCTTTAATCTGCTGGAGTACCATGGAACACCGGTGATCATTCTGGTCACTTGGTCTGGGGCAATACCAGTCAACATGGTGGTGAAGTCACCG 
lenght =  99 
---------------------------



numero =  11 
 ATGGCAGCGACACCAGCAGCGATTGAAGTTAATTTGACCATTGTATTTGTTTTGTTTGTTAGTGCTGATGTAATCTTAACAAGAAATAGTGAAATGAAAGCGCATACCTCAAAGGCATATAGT 
lenght =  123 
---------------------------



numero =  12 
 ATGGAGATGCTCTTGTTTCTGAACGAATCATACATCTTTCATAGGTTTCGTATGTGGAGTATTGTTTTATGGCACTCATGTGTATTCGTATGCGCAGAATGTGGGAATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAAGTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTTTAGATTTGGACCCTCGTTCAGAAGCTTACTGTCTAAGCCATCATTTGGTGTGTCCTAAACGGTTTCCATGCAAAGCAACATCTTTGTTACTCATTCCTGAAGGT 
lenght =  303 
---------------------------



numero =  13 
 ATGCTCTTGTTTCTGAACGAATCATACATCTTTCATAGGTTTCGTATGTGGAGTATTGTTTTATGGCACTCATGTGTATTCGTATGCGCAGAATGTGGGAATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAAGTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTTTAGATTTGGACCCTCGTTCAGAAGCTTACTGTCTAAGCCATCATTTGGTGTGTCCTAAACGGTTTCCATGCAAAGCAACATCTTTGTTACTCATTCCTGAAGGT 
lenght =  297 
---------------------------



numero =  14 
 ATGTGGAGTATTGTTTTATGGCACTCATGTGTATTCGTATGCGCAGAATGTGGGAATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAAGTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTTTAGATTTGGACCCTCGTTCAGAAGCTTACTGTCTAAGCCATCATTTGGTGTGTCCTAAACGGTTTCCATGCAAAGCAACATCTTTGTTACTCATTCCTGAAGGT 
lenght =  252 
---------------------------



numero =  15 
 ATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAAGTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTT 
lenght =  93 
---------------------------



numero =  16 
 ATGATAATAATATTTATAGAATTGTGTAGAATTGCAGATTCCCTTTTATGGATTCCTAAATCCTGGAGGAGAACTTCTAGTATATCTACATACCTAATATTA 
lenght =  102 
---------------------------



numero =  17 
 ATGGAATCCCAACAATTACATCAAAATCCACATTCTCTACACCAATACCATCGACGAGAGCTTCTAGTAAATTGTATACATAACAGTATAACCCTTACCAACAATGGAATCTCAAAGATTATTAAATTATTCACAGACTCTGAGGATTCGGGTAAAATAGGGTATTTAACTGGTTACCGGAAAGGTTTAGAAAATTCGTGGAGGGTTGGCCGAGTGGTC 
lenght =  219 
---------------------------



numero =  18 
 ATGATGTGTAGCGCATTAGTCTTCTGCATTCATATTATCAGTGGTATACCGTTTGGTATATGCTTTCCAATCATGAAGTGTTGGCTCTACTCTATA 
lenght =  96 
---------------------------



numero =  19 
 ATGTGTAGCGCATTAGTCTTCTGCATTCATATTATCAGTGGTATACCGTTTGGTATATGCTTTCCAATCATGAAGTGTTGGCTCTACTCTATA 
lenght =  93 
---------------------------



numero =  20 
 ATGCTGCGACAGAACTTTTCTTCTCTTCCAATTCTTTTATCTTCGCCAATAACGCCTTCTTTTTTCGTGCTTGTATTTCTAAAATTTCGGCCAGGTATTGTAAATATTCGACCGTTCTATCCAAAA 
lenght =  126 
---------------------------



numero =  21 
 ATGGTGGAACCAACTGGCCGAGTTCTTTTATCTTTTGCTTTATTAATTCTCTTCTTCTCCTTTCGACGGCATTATGAAACTCTCTTTTGCGCCTCAGTTTCTCATCAGAAGTTAACCCGCCTAAAATCTTTGGAACACTTCCAGGTCCTATATTTTCAGTCATATTGCTACTTATTGAAGTGTGTCTTGTTCTGGGTGTGTTTATGCTACCATGCC 
lenght =  216 
---------------------------



numero =  22 
 ATGCTACCATGCCTAAAAGAAGATGAAAGGAAACTTCCTGCACGAAATGACGATGATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTA 
lenght =  120 
---------------------------



numero =  23 
 ATGAAAGGAAACTTCCTGCACGAAATGACGATGATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAGAAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAAT 
lenght =  144 
---------------------------



numero =  24 
 ATGACGATGATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAGAAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAAT 
lenght =  120 
---------------------------



numero =  25 
 ATGATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAGAAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAAT 
lenght =  114 
---------------------------



numero =  26 
 ATGGTGATCTTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAGAAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAAT 
lenght =  111 
---------------------------
```

I can get the start position in my sequence of all the found ORFs with :

```
b = [[m.start(1), m.end(1)] for m in pattern.finditer(sequence)]

print(b, len(b))
```

result a list of tuples :

```
[(2, 302), (316, 400), (373, 400), (404, 479), (421, 505), 
(478, 505), (508, 556), (524, 776), (702, 711), (807, 822), 
(907, 1096), (971, 983), (982, 1096), (1014, 1032), (1046, 1055), 
(1064, 1067), (1117, 1141), (1143, 1260), (1340, 1355), (1354, 1378), 
(1370, 1553), (1432, 1585), (1457, 1553), (1485, 1590), (1606, 1663),
 (1626, 1647), (1754, 1769), (1830, 1929),

.........................................
```

but cannot filter for `m.end() - m.start() > 90` in the one liner `b`

any help ??

**EDITED :**

```
b = [[m.start(1), m.end(1)] for m in pattern.finditer(sequence) if (m.end(1) - m.start(1)) > 90]
```

should work only cant get found string with `m.group()`

as an example for first match I get:

`2, 302, <re.Match object; span=(2, 2), match=''>` with `m.group()` = `''`

**EDITED 2:**

I can get the found substring using  `m.groups()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The code is,

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
frame = 2
myseq = myseq[frame:]
bioseq = Seq(myseq)
fullaa = bioseq.translate()
for aa in fullaa.split("*"):
    print (aa)
```

The sequence is below the `-----`

The output looks like open readingframe2. The first protein is:

> MQYSDIYIYPNTTLTLPYFNPSNLSLNLPSHYPTSPLVTLSHSTIPLPTTIHPSTYYHQSTVHHNRYPPISHIQLHYHLPCHYSTIHHLLLTILLFYPPY

This meets with the requirements ... the remaining output is below ... it looks like a eukaryotic with introns. It feels like a home-work question.

---

**Edit** Blasted it, its a yeast protein

> RecName: Full=Putative uncharacterized protein YBL109W [Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288C]
> Sequence ID: P89495.3

The hit is 100%

---

Remaining output

```
NVNK
S
IIHIYLPYHFIPPHITCHTHLHLYTDMPYAHGCYSIYHSQTYPTLTFYSTP
PISH
ISTKCTHIIMHGTCLSGLYPEPFTHNSHDYPHFNIYISFGGPKYCITALNTYVIPLLHHILTTQIIYTYANITKKLPLKSPKHKNYLSFNFTK
THSIAYLYHHDVINVKVP
YYHLLERIPFQNISNFHRPYIRIICHLTVVTLYIHRETIR
WLKLMPVL
YNCILFPFSYAIRNILKA
LMHL
SCM
HYSYEETISKEDDTVICTLFL
NYNETSNNPTIL
LISAVY
NGRYDIVSLHLTTLYLIVDKTLTPQLYF
LQLQQTIPNHKS
YFRCQKMRISK
EFGTMTCNSTTLICNLVLRSDAYSIWPDATRQKMKKEAATHFYGRTKCCEVIRFQFHYCLLDILC
LYYRPRFFYNSVKVSFLCSSYS
NASRTPSLIK
VYNINIHLYNRRYLYHQKK
FFILFFHYFSLSMDFHS
RHHSLVCDSVDTVLG
STGDGWL
SAGVPWNTGDHSGHLVWGNTSQHGGEVTVVENGFSNFDWVGFSWVGGLEHVVLGQVSSDIRDVDTQFHQVDSFVRLS
SGGCRKQ
QRWQRHQQRLKLI
PLYLFCLLVLM
S
QEIVK
KRIPQRHIVEAALFIPVPPSVITT
TIR
QTLI
HLTYSPYLIFHTISLSLWRCSCF
TNHTSFIGFVCGVLFYGTHVYSYAQNVGMPIIGVPGGALKNPFARLLSFRFQSKRISEF
IWTLVQKLTV
AIIWCVLNGFHAKQHLCYSFLKVE
KIATMCRESYIVRF
RLVRIIKAVNRINIRKASKVHS
ENS
HVKICVYEMCQGPSIA
LTPLQE
VTFFTLKRQRGHILKSHFQTHLQFATTDNNIMIGWYDVISCHIFLIIALVTSLQLLG
NSKISFL

YSSYQYIITCRKRR
HKDRQTVFKYNGSWNARIDNVTGY
MTKYK
KKKKKKSSNTIMWKYRFHFEDSNCWNKNQLSSTN
YLRY
YIIIYGVRR
RK

EIVI
ISGS
NARIDNVIGSMNINI
NDDNNIYRIV
NCRFPFMDS
ILEENF
YIYIPNIIALITMESQQLHQNPHSLHQYHRRELLVNCIHNSITLTNNGISKIIKLFTDSEDSGKIGYLTGYRKGLENSWRVGRVV
GGRLKICWTVVRASSNLAFIFRIHFIVGHFISCRVH
KIINQIII
PMGHFFDETHVYSSIRS
YCTYDYQ
HQNNHRAYAILKYIIAVKYDV
RISLLHSYYQWYTVWYMLSNHEVLALLYINSTSIDFLNK
VTQVSFPLIQVIYILATPNYKALKIISYPIAGSTCIYYTLLITNLLHI
QYA

Y
CI
IIS
KKITWVLLT
LHLEYIKF
RINISKVLDITKNNSE
F
ILLHIILLAYLFHSFQNVACKRY
YSALFCCNS
FFHYIILRVRKRLTFSQ
KEQT
ILKFYCFCLPDLFQI
FFPANKTINYPEPNSKR
SAGLELSSPNINFALSSASIKSPDKNSFNSS
MFVCG
LSIVPA
LWLPTESYNGGSQLCNSALLFCSFIKAFGTDLISIILSSLFSLLFCPELAWWLLVKGDNAATELFFSSNSFIFANNAFFFRACISKISARYCKYSTVLSKMIPLFGLICLPRSS
FNKDGGTNWPSSFIFCFINSLLLLSTAL
NSLLRLSFSSEVNPPKIFGTLPGPIFSVILLLIEVCLVLGVFMLPCLKEDERKLPARNDDDGDLTFGEYVEDTDAGPKLCGL
ENDDEYVFGVIISELMLEDKEELKSSVKLYIVSSVPC
NKKSCGNSAFKPSCCCNGVFIA
```

---

```
myseq = "GCATGCAATACAGTGACATATATATATACCCTAACACTACCCTAACCCTACCCTATTTCA\
ACCCTTCCAACCTGTCTCTCAACTTACCCTCACATTACCCTACCTCTCCACTTGTTACCC\
TGTCCCATTCAACCATACCACTCCCAACCACCATCCATCCCTCTACTTACTACCACCAAT\
CAACCGTCCACCATAACCGTTACCCTCCAATTAGCCATATTCAACTTCACTACCACTTAC\
CCTGCCATTACTCTACCATCCACCATCTGCTACTCACCATACTGTTGTTCTACCCTCCAT\
ATTGAAACGTTAACAAATGATCGTAAATAATACACATATACTTACCCTACCACTTTATAC\
CACCACACATCACATGCCATACTCACCTTCACTTGTATACTGATATGCCATACGCACACG\
GATGCTACAGTATATACCACTCTCAAACTTACCCTACTCTCACATTCTACTCCACTCCAT\
GACCCATCTCTCACTAAATCAGTACTAAATGCACCCACATCATTATGCACGGCACTTGCC\
TCAGCGGTCTATACCCTGAGCCATTTACCCATAACTCCCACGATTATCCACATTTTAATA\
TCTATATCTCATTCGGCGGGCCCAAATATTGTATAACTGCTCTTAATACATACGTTATAC\
CACTTTTGCACCATATACTAACCACTCAAATTATATACACTTATGCCAATATAACCAAAA\
AATTACCACTAAAATCACCTAAACATAAAAATTATTTATCTTTCAACTTTACGAAATAAA\
CACACTCAATTGCGTATCTATACCACCATGACGTCATTAACGTAAAAGTTCCTTAATATT\
ACCATTTGCTTGAACGGATACCATTTCAGAATATTTCTAACTTTCACAGACCATACATTA\
GAATAATATGCCACCTCACTGTCGTAACACTCTATATTCACCGAGAAACAATACGGTAGT\
GGCTCAAACTCATGCCGGTGCTATGATACAATTGTATCCTATTTCCATTCTCATATGCTA\
TCCGCAATATCCTAAAAGCATAACTGATGCATCTTTAATCTTGTATGTGACACTACTCAT\
ACGAAGAGACTATATCTAAAGAAGACGATACAGTGATATGTACGTTGTTTTTGTAGAATT\
ATAATGAAACGTCAAATAACCCTACTATATTATAACTTATCAGCGCCGTATACTAAAACG\
GACGTTACGATATTGTCTCACTTCATCTTACCACCCTCTATCTTATTGTTGATAAAACAC\
TAACCCCTCAGCTTTATTTCTAGTTACAGTTACAACAAACTATCCCAAACCATAAATCTT\
AATATTTTAGGTGTCAAAAAATGAGGATCTCCAAATGAGAGTTTGGTACCATGACTTGTA\
ACTCCACTACCCTGATCTGCAATCTTGTTCTTAGAAGTGACGCATACTCTATATGGCCCG\
ACGCGACGCGCCAAAAAATGAAAAAAGAAGCAGCGACTCATTTTTATGGAAGGACAAAGT\
GCTGCGAAGTCATACGCTTCCAATTTCATTATTGTTTATTGGACATACTCTGTTAGCTTT\
ATTACCGTCCACGCTTTTTCTACAATAGTGTAAAAGTTTCTTTCTTATGTTCATCGTATT\
CATAAAATGCTTCACGAACACCGTCATTGATCAAATAGGTTTATAATATTAATATACATT\
TATATAATCGGCGGTATTTATATCATCAAAAAAAGTAGTTTTTTATTTTATTTTTTCATT\
ACTTTTCACTGTCTATGGATTTTCATTCGTAAAGGCATCACTCCCTAGTTTGCGATAGTG\
TAGATACCGTCCTTGGATAGAGCACTGGAGATGGCTGGCTTTAATCTGCTGGAGTACCAT\
GGAACACCGGTGATCATTCTGGTCACTTGGTCTGGGGCAATACCAGTCAACATGGTGGTG\
AAGTCACCGTAGTTGAAAACGGCTTCAGCAACTTCGACTGGGTAGGTTTCAGTTGGGTGG\
GCGGCTTGGAACATGTAGTATTGGGCCAAGTGAGCTCTGATATCAGAGACGTAGACACCC\
AATTCCACCAAGTTGACTCTTTCGTCAGATTGAGCTAGAGTGGTGGTTGCAGAAAGCAGT\
AGCAGCGATGGCAGCGACACCAGCAGCGATTGAAGTTAATTTGACCATTGTATTTGTTTT\
GTTTGTTAGTGCTGATGTAATCTTAACAAGAAATAGTGAAATGAAAGCGCATACCTCAAA\
GGCATATAGTTGAAGCAGCTCTATTTATACCCGTTCCTCCATCTGTCATCACTACTTAAA\
CGATTCGTTAACAGACGCTCATTTAGCACCTCACATATTCTCCATATCTCATCTTTCACA\
CAATCTCATTATCTCTATGGAGATGCTCTTGTTTCTGAACGAATCATACATCTTTCATAG\
GTTTCGTATGTGGAGTATTGTTTTATGGCACTCATGTGTATTCGTATGCGCAGAATGTGG\
GAATGCCTATTATAGGGGTGCCGGGGGGTGCCTTGAAAAACCCTTTTGCGCGCCTGTTAA\
GTTTCCGTTTTCAGTCAAAAAGAATATCCGAATTTTAGATTTGGACCCTCGTTCAGAAGC\
TTACTGTCTAAGCCATCATTTGGTGTGTCCTAAACGGTTTCCATGCAAAGCAACATCTTT\
GTTACTCATTCCTGAAGGTTGAATAAAAAATAGCAACCATGTGCAGGGAGTCGTATATTG\
TTAGATTCTAGAGACTTGTACGCATCATCAAAGCTGTAAATAGAATAAACATACGCAAGG\
CGTCAAAAGTGCATAGTTAAGAAAATTCCTGACATGTGAAAATATGTGTTTATGAAATGT\
GTCAAGGCCCGTCTATAGCGTAGTTAACCCCTCTGCAGGAGTAAGTGACTTTTTTTACGC\
TCAAAAGGCAACGAGGGCACATACTTAAAAGTCATTTTCAAACACATCTGCAGTTTGCAA\
CGACAGATAACAATATTATGATAGGATGGTATGATGTTATTAGCTGCCACATATTTTTAA\
TAATAGCATTAGTCACGTCTCTTCAATTGTTGGGATGAAACTCTAAAATATCATTCCTTT\
AGTAGTATTCCAGTTACCAGTATATTATCACATGCCGAAAAAGAAGATGACATAAAGATC\
GACAAACAGTCTTCAAATATAATGGAAGCTGGAATGCAAGGATTGATAATGTAACAGGAT\
ACTGAATGACAAAGTATAAATGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGTAGTAATACTATTATGT\
GGAAATACCGATTCCATTTTGAGGATTCCAATTGTTGGAATAAAAATCAACTATCATCTA\
CTAACTAGTATTTACGTTACTAGTATATTATCATATACGGTGTTAGAAGATGACGCAAAT\
GATGAGAAATAGTCATCTAAATTAGTGGAAGCTGAAACGCAAGGATTGATAATGTAATAG\
GATCAATGAATATTAACATATAAAACGATGATAATAATATTTATAGAATTGTGTAGAATT\
GCAGATTCCCTTTTATGGATTCCTAAATCCTGGAGGAGAACTTCTAGTATATCTACATAC\
CTAATATTATAGCCTTAATCACAATGGAATCCCAACAATTACATCAAAATCCACATTCTC\
TACACCAATACCATCGACGAGAGCTTCTAGTAAATTGTATACATAACAGTATAACCCTTA\
CCAACAATGGAATCTCAAAGATTATTAAATTATTCACAGACTCTGAGGATTCGGGTAAAA\
TAGGGTATTTAACTGGTTACCGGAAAGGTTTAGAAAATTCGTGGAGGGTTGGCCGAGTGG\
TCTAAGGCGGCAGACTTAAGATCTGTTGGACGGTTGTCCGCGCGAGTTCGAACCTCGCAT\
TCATTTTCCGGATCCACTTTATAGTGGGTCACTTCATCTCTTGTAGGGTTCACTGAAAGA\
TAATCAATCAAATTATCATATGACCAATGGGTCACTTTTTTGATGAGACCCATGTTTATT\
CTTCTATACGTTCGTGATACTGCACTTACGACTACCAGTAACATCAGAATAACCATAGAG\
CTTATGCTATCTTGAAATATATCATCGCCGTAAAGTATGATGTGTAGCGCATTAGTCTTC\
TGCATTCATATTATCAGTGGTATACCGTTTGGTATATGCTTTCCAATCATGAAGTGTTGG\
CTCTACTCTATATAAATTCGACATCCATTGATTTTCTCAATAAATGAGTTACCCAAGTAA\
GCTTTCCATTGATACAAGTGATCTACATTCTTGCGACGCCAAATTATAAAGCACTAAAAA\
TCATATCATACCCAATTGCGGGCAGCACATGTATATATTATACACTACTTATAACTAACC\
TTCTTCATATATAACAATATGCCTGATAATACTAATGCATTTAAATCATATCATGAAAGA\
AAATTACATGGGTTTTATTGACATAATTGCATTTAGAATACATAAAATTCTAAAGAATTA\
ATATATCCAAAGTATTAGACATAACCAAGAATAATAGTGAATAATTTTAGATTTTGTTAC\
ATATAATTCTGCTTGCCTATCTCTTCCACTCTTTTCAAAACGTTGCATGTAAGCGTTACT\
AATATTCCGCTTTATTTTGTTGCAATTCCTAATTTTTTCATTACATTATCTTGCGAGTAC\
GGAAGCGATTAACGTTCTCCCAATAGAAGGAACAAACATAGATATTGAAGTTTTACTGCT\
TTTGCTTACCTGACCTTTTTCAAATTTAATTTTTTCCCGCTAATAAGACCATAAACTACC\
CCGAACCAAATTCTAAAAGATAGTCAGCTGGATTAGAGTTGTCATCTCCAAACATTAATT\
TTGCATTATCTTCGGCTTCAATCAAATCGCCTGATAAGAACTCCTTTAATTCTTCATGAA\
TGTTTGTATGTGGATGACTCTCCATAGTGCCAGCATGATTGTGGTTACCGACCGAATCAT\
ATAACGGTGGCTCCCAATTGTGCAATTCAGCCTTACTATTTTGTTCATTCATCAAAGCAT\
TTGGGACAGATCTAATATCTATAATTCTTTCCTCACTATTCTCGCTATTATTTTGCCCCG\
AACTGGCATGGTGGTTATTGGTAAAAGGAGATAATGCTGCGACAGAACTTTTCTTCTCTT\
CCAATTCTTTTATCTTCGCCAATAACGCCTTCTTTTTTCGTGCTTGTATTTCTAAAATTT\
CGGCCAGGTATTGTAAATATTCGACCGTTCTATCCAAAATGATACCCTTATTTGGTTTGA\
TTTGTTTACCTAGGTCATCGTAATTCAATAAAGATGGTGGAACCAACTGGCCGAGTTCTT\
TTATCTTTTGCTTTATTAATTCTCTTCTTCTCCTTTCGACGGCATTATGAAACTCTCTTT\
TGCGCCTCAGTTTCTCATCAGAAGTTAACCCGCCTAAAATCTTTGGAACACTTCCAGGTC\
CTATATTTTCAGTCATATTGCTACTTATTGAAGTGTGTCTTGTTCTGGGTGTGTTTATGC\
TACCATGCCTAAAAGAAGATGAAAGGAAACTTCCTGCACGAAATGACGATGATGGTGATC\
TTACCTTTGGGGAATATGTGGAAGATACGGATGCTGGGCCCAAGCTTTGTGGATTATAAG\
AAAATGATGATGAATATGTGTTTGGTGTCATCATATCAGAATTGATGCTAGAAGATAAAG\
AGGAGCTCAAATCATCAGTTAAGTTATACATTGTGTCATCGGTGCCATGCTGAAATAAAA\
AGTCATGTGGTAACTCAGCTTTTAAGCCTTCTTGTTGCTGTAATGGAGTATTCATTGCTC"
```